# Why do long HTTP round trip-times stall my Tornado AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, tornado

I'm using Tornado to send requests in rapid, periodic succession (every 0.1s or even 0.01s) to a server. For this, I'm using `AsyncHttpClient.fetch` with a callback to handle the response.
Here's a very simple code to show what I mean:

```
from functools import partial
from tornado import gen, locks, httpclient
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

    # usually many of these running on the same thread, maybe requesting the same server
 @gen.coroutine
 def send_request(url, interval):
    wakeup_condition = locks.Condition()
    #using this to allow requests to send immediately
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(max_clients=1000) 

    for i in range(300):
        req_time = datetime.now()

        current_callback = partial(handle_response, req_time)
        http_client.fetch(url, current_callback, method='GET')
        yield wakeup_condition.wait(timeout=timedelta(seconds=interval))

def handle_response(req_time,  response):
    resp_time = datetime.now()
    write_to_log(req_time, resp_time, resp_time - req_time) #opens the log and writes to it
```

When I was testing it against a local server, it was working fine, the requests were being sent on time, the round trip time was obviously minimal.
However, when I test it against a remote server, with larger round trip times (especially for higher request loads), the request timing gets messed up by multiple seconds: The period of wait between each request becomes much larger than the desired period.

How come? I thought the async code wouldn't be affected by the roundtrip time since it isn't blocking while waiting for the response. Is there any known solution to this?

Comment: How do you call `send_request`? And what `current_callback` does? If you call `send_request` "parallely" and `current_callback` takes some significant time then it might happen that you stack lots of requests (since round trip takes some time) and when they comeback they are processed one by one slowing down everything (including new request scheduling) because of the single thread nature. Thus the wait time becomes longer.

Comment: So it seems that this actually **is** due to async (you wouldn't have that problem with threads). The only workaround I see is to make the wait period shorter and wait again if the timeout is not reached.

Comment: @freakish, how is this due to async? I spent quite a bit of time changing from threads to async because threads were doing much worse with large loads and consuming a lot of memory to boot.

Comment: `current_callback` is a partial of `handle_response` which essentially writes to files. Wouldn't the explanation you described have the same behavior if the round trip time was shorter? Since the number of requests, and therefore responses handled is the same in both cases, so the work load should be the same.

Comment: Well if round trip is much shorter then wait interval then all responses can in theory be processed before timeout fires. Thus there is no lag. But if round time is around timeout and some processing takes place during that time (e.g. the response processing) then it is natural that the timeout will happen some time after it should. This happens because the timeout cannot fire in parallel due to single threaded nature of async. But this theory heavily depends on the rest of the code. Does it make more sense now? BTW do you do async writes to files? This might matter as well.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not doing aync writes to files. However, I tried commenting out the file writing and the results didn't seem to change much. However, I see what you're saying: Once the roundtrip time is bigger than the wait interval, you have a possibility that the timings conflict. I'll have to test out with async writes to see how that performs.

Comment: It turns out normal file writing does not hurt the timing at all (tried commenting out the file writing and all stayed the same). However, the issue was coming from the fact that the URL I was using was HTTPS, which very significantly deteriorating performance. HTTP URLs, on the other hand, seem much less impacted.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting. I'm not sure but HTTPS overhead should not be that big? Weird.

Comment: @freakish the second problem had to do with DNS calls being repeated at each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering and tcpdumping, I've concluded that two things were  really slowing down my coroutine. With these two corrected stalling has gone down enormously drastically and the `timeout` in `yield wakeup_condition.wait(timeout=timedelta(seconds=interval))` is much better respected:

1. The computer I'm running on doesn't seem to be caching DNS, which for AsyncHTTPClient seem to be a blocking network call. As such every coroutine sending requests has the added time to wait for the DNS to resolve. Tornado docs say:

> tornado.httpclient in the default configuration blocks on DNS
>   resolution but not on other network access (to mitigate this use
>   `ThreadedResolver` or a `tornado.curl_httpclient` with a
>   properly-configured build of `libcurl`).

...and in [the AsynHTTPClient docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html)

> To select curl_httpclient, call AsyncHTTPClient.configure at startup:
>
> `AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")`

I ended up implementing my own thread which resolves and caches DNS, however, and that resolved the issue by issuing the request directly to the IP address.

2. The URL I was using was HTTPS, changing to a HTTP url improved performance. For my use case that's not always possible, but it's good to be able to localize part of the issue