# how to use tornado to get image and write it in a file?

Tags: python, tornado

I have a url :"https://findicons.com/files/icons/2787/beautiful_flat_icons/128/running.png"

I want to get the image and write it to file , i write the code as follow:

```
import urllib.request
web = urllib.request.urlopen(iturl)
itdata = web.read()
f = open(str(cou) + '.png', "wb")
cou = cou + 1
f.write(itdata)
f.close()
```

My question is ,if i have many urls to download  ,how can i implement it by coroutine of tornado?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Tornado, how to do non-blocking file read/write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810868/in-tornado-how-to-do-non-blocking-file-read-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the entire code, just something I came up with in 5 mins but it should give you enough information to satisfy your requirements. If you have any questions or further explanation is required, please let me know.

```py
from tornado import gen, httpclient, ioloop

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield client.fetch(
        'https://findicons.com/files/icons/2787/beautiful_flat_icons/128/running.png',
        download_image,
        follow_redirects = True)

@gen.coroutine
def download_image(response):
    buffer_size = 1024
    filename = response.request.url.split('/')[-1]  # this is not always reliable
    with open(filename, 'ab') as img:
        while True:
            chunk = response.buffer.read(buffer_size)
            if chunk == '':
                break
            img.write(chunk)
            yield

ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

### References

- [Tornado Issue #1616](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1616)
- [Examples of RequestHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#example-code)